# C# IntPtr and ProcessorAffinity - how to exceed 32 bits?

Tags: c#, process, 64-bit

I have a computer with more than 31 cpu cores. I would like to assign a process to cpu cores beyond the 31st. My issue is that IntPtr resolves to 32 bit integer on this machine. It is a 64-bit machine running 64-bit operating system. This seems to defy what is stated by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The IntPtr type is designed to be an integer whose size is
>   platform-specific. That is, an instance of this type is expected to be
>   32-bits on 32-bit hardware and operating systems, and 64-bits on
>   64-bit hardware and operating systems.

Here is how I am constructing the IntPtr:

```
public static IntPtr GetCpuBinaryValue(int cpuIndex)
{
    // The IntPtr type is designed to be an integer whose size is platform - specific.
    // That is, an instance of this type is expected to be 32 - bits on 32 - bit hardware and operating systems,
    // and 64 - bits on 64 - bit hardware and operating systems.


    IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(2, cpuIndex)));
    return ptr;
}
```

And to continue the example, here is how I set the ProcessorAffinity:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
    // set which processor to run the process on
                process.ProcessorAffinity = GetCpuBinaryValue(coreIndex);
...
```

For example, I can pass in the value "0" and it will return an IntPtr (32-bit) with mask of 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001

If I pass in "31" it will return 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

What I desire is for it to cast as 64 bit, for example if I pass in the value "32" it will return: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Is there a way to get around this issue? It is stubbornly stuck on 32-bit.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: This is a limitation in the underlying winapi function, SetProcessAffinityMask().  In 32-bit mode it can handle only 32 processors.  Nothing you can do about this if you can't bump up to AnyCPU, your hardware is considerably more powerful than your software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running in `x86` or `Any CPU`. `IntPtr` is platform-specific, but it also depends on the process itself. If the Process is running in 64-bit mode, then pointers will be 64-bit, and if the process is running in 32-bit, then pointers will be 32-bit.

If you switch to explicitly running as `x64` (as described in [How to: Configure Projects to Target Platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx)), then the overflow exception goes away, and the correct value seems to be stored in the return value.

Comment: A side note to anyone else stuck on this: all projects and executables have to be 64-bit for this to work. In my case - while I had set 64-bit the main "console launch" application - it had been utilizing a second console compiled in 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread & OP was not asking about setting on a running process, but if you happen to be stetting the ProcessorAffinity from PowerShell, you can check the number of bytes:

`[IntPtr]::Size`

If you run it on x86 version of Powershell you will see size is 4 and you can only address 32 cores.  Run the x64 version of Powershell and the size will be 8 bytes for IntPtr and you will be able to set the affinity.